# What is the most suitable dataset?

Tags: algorithm, dataset, data-mining

I am making a data mining application that can classify patients to their correct diagnosis, based on their symptoms. I was wondering if anyone knew what is the most suitable dataset I need and from where I can get it from. Is it a better approach to specialise in a certain area (ie Heart disease, diabetes etc) or should I classify patients on the whole, based on all types off illnesses? Ideally I want the dataset to be based on patients visits to their doctor. Therefore it should contain symptons and the diagnosis. However if I can get a dataset that contains other attributes such as age, gender etc then that would be even better. If anyone can help me and point me towards a suitable dataset then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Gaining access to medical information is tricky and problematic due to confidentiality. good luck with that..

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/heckerman/hn92cbr.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately there is no standard way of keeping track of "symptoms". Usually hospitals keep track of diagnoses and procedures. See ICD9 standard. You can probably get such dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some example datasets out there.

For example in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) there is a dataset with diabetes data. These are the variables:

```
%    1. Number of times pregnant
%    2. Plasma glucose concentration a 2 hours in an oral glucose tolerance test
%    3. Diastolic blood pressure (mm Hg)
%    4. Triceps skin fold thickness (mm)
%    5. 2-Hour serum insulin (mu U/ml)
%    6. Body mass index (weight in kg/(height in m)^2)
%    7. Diabetes pedigree function
%    8. Age (years)
%    9. Class variable (0 or 1)
```

Also have a look at this page for a list of some more publicly available resources (some of which may have medical background):

- http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/datasets.html